# Writing a BASH command to print a range

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, sed, scripting

Sample data (foo)

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
```

To get the desired lines hardcoded I have used

```
sed -n '1,3p' foo
```

Which returns to expected outcome

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Now I need to a script where the range1, range2 & file-name are taken as command-line arguments. So i tried

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -n '$1,$2p'
```

When running the scripting using

```
sh print_lines.sh 2 4 foo
```

I get the following error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unknown command: `1'
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Try `sed -n "$1,${2}p" "$3"`

Comment: To expand the parameters, you need to put them in double quotes

Comment: And putting `#!/bin/bash` in the script but then invoking it with `sh` makes little sense.

Comment: Great issue solved! Thanks alot